# Show validation messages of a group on first load of page

Tags: asp.net, validation

I checked SO for a solution but I didn't come to anything useful, they were either unanswered [like this orphan link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381547/how-to-trigger-validation-on-first-load) or irrelevant. Now I ask it here:

*Is it possible to make validators show their messages on first load of the page?*

I have a couple of validators (required, custom, range ...) on my page, and I have grouped them. I want the required validation group show their messages on first load (when !page.IsPostBack) so my customer can see what is mandotary and what is not at the first glance.

Comment: thanks every one, finally my problem handled. all answers were good enough for a +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code should work for your requirement.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // for all validators to fire, first time
        Page.Validate();
        // Or Only validators under a specific group will fire
        Page.Validate("ValidationGroupName");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Validate()` on the validator(s) from `Page_Load`.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    this.UserNameRequired.Validate();
    // and all the other mandatory validators
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure... just call the `submit` method of your form.

Isn't that what you really need? submit the form and get all messages?

```
$(function() {

    // this will submit the form, but as you have validation, 
    // it will fire up all validations
    $("form").submit(); 

});
```

It's a simple trick, that I sometimes do.